# Multiple git commands in single command executed in order they are encountered by compiler

Tags: bash, git-bash, combiners, git

I have following list of commands that I run in respective order so that a source project can be committed and pushed to the repository on Bitbucket:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://[BitBucket Username]@bitbucket.org/[BitBucket Username]/[BitBucket Repository Name].git
git config user.name "[BitBucket Username]"
git config user.email "[BitBucket Email ID]"
## if email doesn't work then use below ##
git config --global user.email \<\>
git add *
git commit -m "[Comment]"
git push -u origin master
```

Now instead of putting each and every line at their respective time and order, I want to know, if there is a possibility that I can chain all these into single `git` command and maintain the same order, something like below ?

```
git init remote add origin https://[BitBucket Username]@bitbucket.org/[BitBucket Username]/[BitBucket Repository Name].git  config user.name "[Username]" ....
```

Or atleast combine multiple same category params like below ?

```
git config user.name "[BitBucket Username]" user.email "[BitBucket Email ID]"
```

I need to know possibility of both scenarios with examples.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? What is the problem with the line-by-line solution?

Comment: Would a shell script in `~/bin` work? Otherwise add a git alias in your user's `~/.gitconfig` file to execute a shell function (IIRC there's samples in the documentation), e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14994923/112968

Comment: For Linux shell script is good, but I have gitbash on Windows system and I am not as good with Win batch as with Linux shell. Can you give me a Windows based suggestion ?

Comment: With stock `git`, no, you can't. You can, however, create a shell script called `git-whatever` somewhere in the PATH, containing all your commands, using parameters if needed, and thus you could execute `git whatever` (note the lack of the space)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We can use list off command in single command for example:

```
git add . && git commit -m "updated pom file" && git push
```

or:

```
git stash pop && git add . && git commit -m "updated pom file" && git push
```

- `&&` -> if 1st command successfully executes then execute next command else it won't execute next command.
- `&` -  it executes all the command
- `||` -  execute next command if 1st one failed

Comment: This only works on CMD or Git Bash on Windows, not on PowerShell

Comment: Powershell is not a shell, i.e. it's not designed to run external programs. You will have to do more complicated shenanigans in order to interop powershell with other processes.

Answer (score 15):

If you are in a Windows Powershell:

```
git add . ; git commit -m "Testing one line command" ; git push
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have gitbash on Windows system and I am not as good with Win batch as with Linux shell.

You still can write a bash script (interpreted by the [msys2 bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) embedded [with Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)).
As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824526/multiple-git-commands-in-single-command-executed-in-order-they-are-encountered-b/43825617#comment74687271_43824526) by [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen), and as I mentioned before in "[Which shell used for git '!' aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445884/6309)", you can write a shell script in a file (in your %PATH%) named `git-xxx`, and call it with `git xxx`.
That script would begin with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: The following does not work, can I do it? `cmd=('add .' "commit -m $commit");
for elem in ${cmd[@]} ; do;
git "$elem" &&;
# echo -n "$elem";
done;` it creates a new line for every word in the element array. echo -n can suppress newlines, but does not help because I do not want to echo but run git.

Comment: @Timo I would use double quotes consistently, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774197/6309

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called reset.txt and in that file I have the commands

git reset --hard
git clean -d -f
[this is a newline - very important to have it]

I just copy and paste this into my terminal and it executes the commands in order.