# How to execute a command represented by an array in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

This question is different from [Execute an array of string describing shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773738/execute-an-array-of-string-describing-shell-command).

For example, we have an array

```
myarr=( echo hello you )
```

How to execute it as one command, i.e. run `echo hello you` itself?

Comment: Command as array, command as variable... There are functions for that.

Comment: You did not demonstrate that "This question is different from Execute an array of string describing shell command." [Execute an array of string describing shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773738/execute-an-array-of-string-describing-shell-command), So I vote to close it as this exact duplicate. In other words, you made a strong claim that need some strong backing.

Comment: The other question is related, but not really the same. It is about an array of strings being one full command each. This is about an array of strings that need to put together to make one full command.

Comment: @IsaIkari, please review your accepted answer in light of the demonstration at https://ideone.com/ZVG3uq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `[@]` (turn the array into a space-separated string):

```
$ myarr=( echo hello you )
$ "${myarr[@]}"
hello you
```

Note: this works, but I would personally find it more correct to use `eval`:

```
$ eval "${myarr[@]}"
hello you
```

**EDIT**: as pointed out in the comments below, quotes are needed and the solution with `eval` is not correct, although it works in this case.

Comment: You need double quotes anyway `"${myarr[@]}"` or it will split arguments containing spaces, tabs or newlines

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: same for the first version without `eval`

Comment: All the advice in this answer, _including_ the version with `eval`, is buggy if tested with a more interesting array -- it only appears to work because the sample data is so simple little can go wrong. Try `myarr=( printf ' - %s\n' "first word" "second word" )` -- if you run `"${myarr[@]}"` _with the quotes_ it does the right thing (printing `- first word` and `- second word` each on a separate line). It's buggy as `eval "${myarr[@]}"`, and also buggy as `${myarr[@]}`. See the above demonstrated at https://ideone.com/ZVG3uq

Comment: (This happens because when `eval` is passed multiple arguments it concatenates them together into a single string, then runs that string through the parser -- so quotes that were consumed in deciding where to divide up `eval`'s arguments are completely discarded. In general, to avoid this class of bug, I always advise that only complete strings be passed to `eval`).

Comment: BTW, if you _do_ want to make it work with eval, you can do it like this: `printf -v myarr_q '%q ' "${myarr[@]}"; eval "$myarr_q"` -- generating an `eval`-safe string and then feeding it into `eval`. But that's a bit silly in a situation where you don't really need `eval` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

To work correctly in all cases, you **must** put quotes around your expansion.

```
myarr=( printf ' - %s\n' "first line" "second line" )
"${myarr[@]}"
```

...correctly writes as output:

```
 - first line
 - second line
```

This DOES NOT WORK if you leave out the quotes. It also does not work if you use `eval`.

---

#### Broken Way 1: Leaving Out Quotes

```
myarr=( printf ' - %s\n' "first line" "second line" )
${myarr[@]}
```

...writes only:

```
-
```

---

#### Broken Way 2: Using `eval` Inappropriately

```
myarr=( printf ' - %s\n' "first line" "second line" )
eval "${myarr[@]}"
```

...*also* writes only:

```
-
```